# Is there a way to add multiple artists using eyeD3 in python3

Tags: python, metadata, mp3, tagging, eyed3

I tried using `mySong.tag.artist = "Artist 1, Artist 2"` but media players like itunes treat it as one artist. Is there any way to tag the song with Various artists and specify which ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace the comma with a semicolon:

```
mySong.tag.artist = "Artist 1; Artist 2"
```